# unable to start Airflow webserver with python 3.10

Tags: python, numpy, airflow

I installed python 3.10, airflow version  2.2.0
but when I tried to run cmd : airflow  webserver
I got :

```
C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\airflow\configuration.py:270: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and
 slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.version import StrictVersion
WARNING:root:OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'
```

how I can use these setuptools ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at this link.
http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/prerequisites.html

Airflow 2.2 is not certified to run on python 3.10

Comment: 3 months later and it still isn't. This sucks.